# how to make array of cells in vba excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, arraylist, raw-sockets

I want to make array of cells in excel to using VBA to add new row, I used this code

```
Private Sub add_Click()
Sheets("Block B").Range("C8").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown Sheets("Block B").Range("C8:L8").Select  Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
```

But the new line insert in exact raw 8, I want in each click to add a new row in the next row 8, 9, 10, ...

How can I do it ?

Comment: Repeat it for the other two but do it in the order of 10, then 9, then 8

Comment: You want to click a button and insert a new row at a specific row, and for each subsequent click to move down and insert a new row at the next row. View this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484882/inserting-new-row-of-data-in-excel-every-time-user-click-on-command-button)

Answer (score 0):

We must turn the circulation from a lot to a small one.

Try this

```
Sub test()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set Ws = Sheets("Block B")
    With Ws
        For i = 10 To 8 Step -1
            .Range("c" & i).EntireRow.Insert
            .Range("c" & i).Resize(1, 10).Borders.Weight = xlThin
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```